# Have log entries forced to a single line when using p&p EntLib logging block

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I am using the patterns & practices enterprise library (p&p EntLib) logging block to write to a text file.

Some of the log message contain multiple lines which I would like to force to become a single line - in other words replacing the `\r` & `\n` with a space in the log messages prior to them being written to the file.

How do I configure the logging block for this, if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory you will need to create a custom formatter, something similar to [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180203030642/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/archive/2008/01/14/118543.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What about performing a string replace on your message to substitute spaces for newlines?

i.e.

Configure your Formatter template something like:

```
<formatters>
  <add template="{timestamp}: {category}: {severity}: {message}"
    type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    name="My Text Formatter" />
</formatters>
```

Then in your code replace the new lines with a space (this could be done in one centralized helper method):

```
string message = @"This is 
the message
to log.";

message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

This should result in a log file that looks like:

```
11/11/2009 2:52:01 PM: My Category Event: Information: This is  the message to log.
11/11/2009 2:53:47 PM: My Category Event: Information: More test to log to the  file.
```